# Why is my SQL Query so slow? both in VBA and SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am currently encountering an issue when running this query both in VBA and in the SQL database.

The query itself works,but it is very slow (normally takes a minute or more for it to retrieve information from the db)

So far I've been using this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim userInput As String
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim cell As Range

    Set cell = Sheet1.Range("H19:I19")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    If cell.Cells(1, 1).value <> "" Then ' Verifica a célula para procurar por um valor
        If Not IsValidFormat(cell.Cells(1, 1).value) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events before showing the message box
            MsgBox "Formato de texto errado!                                                                    Por favor use uma letra e até 3 números (e.x., X111).", vbExclamation, "Erro: Formato de texto errado"
            UnmergeAndClear cell ' Faz o split e limpa os conteúdos
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Liga os eventos do excel outra vez
End If
      
If Not Target Is Nothing And Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I5")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.value <> "" Then
    userInput = Target.value
    

    ' Faz a ligação com a base de dados
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
    conn.CommandTimeout = 0
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=IP;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=.;Password=PASSWORD;"
      
      
    ' Query do valor da fuga,pressão do hélio e data de produção da peça
    strSQL = "SELECT MOTOR_HOUSING_LABEL, REAR_HEAD_LABEL FROM dbo.LineA WHERE PROCESS_LABEL = '" & userInput & "' ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC;"
    
    Debug.Print "Executing SQL Query: " & strSQL
    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
    
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        
        Dim motor As Variant
        Dim rear As Variant

        motor = rs.Fields("MOTOR_HOUSING_LABEL").value
        rear = rs.Fields("REAR_HEAD_LABEL").value
        
        Debug.Print "Motor encontrado na base de dados : " & motor
        Debug.Print "Rear encontrado na base de dados : " & rear
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K5").value = motor
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M5").value = rear
        
    Else
        Debug.Print "Não existe qualquer match na base de dados."
    End If
    
    strSQL = "SELECT ST300_TORQUE, ST400_LEAK_VALUE, ST390_HEPRESS_TEST FROM dbo.LineB WHERE PROCESS_LABEL = '" & userInput & "' ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC;"
    
    Debug.Print "Executing SQL Query: " & strSQL
    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
    
    countSQL = "SELECT COUNT(ST400_LEAK_VALUE) AS LeakCount FROM dbo.LineB WHERE PROCESS_LABEL = '" & userInput & "' AND ST400_LEAK_VALUE IS NOT NULL ;"
    Set countRS = conn.Execute(countSQL)
    
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Dim torqueparafusos As Variant
        Dim leakvalue As Variant
        Dim heliumpress As Variant
    
        heliumpress = rs.Fields("ST390_HEPRESS_TEST").value
        torqueparafusos = rs.Fields("ST300_TORQUE").value
        leakvalue = rs.Fields("ST400_LEAK_VALUE").value

        Debug.Print "Valor de fuga encontrado na base de dados : " & leakvalue
        Debug.Print "Torque encontrado na base de dados : " & torqueparafusos
        Debug.Print "Valor da pressão do hélio encontrada na base de dados : "

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T10").value = torqueparafusos
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S10").value = leakvalue
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U10").value = heliumpress
    
        Dim leakCount As Long
        leakCount = countRS.Fields("LeakCount").value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R10").value = leakCount
    
   Else
       Debug.Print "Não existe qualquer match na base de dados."
   End If
  
   rs.Close
   conn.Close
   Set rs = Nothing
   Set conn = Nothing
```

I'm very new to SQL so I don't know what I may be doing wrong.

The thing is though that I have another workbook with a very similar query to the one I posted and it takes around 2-3 seconds to retrieve the information.

I'm sure that other workbook is getting information from another table that doesn't have nearly as much information as this one but I still don't think it would make that much of a difference

If anyone could help me out or just point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it!

Comment: If the query is slow when run in your query tool (ie. not in VBA) then this is a more a question about query optimization and not about VBA.  Maybe you need an index on your table for "PROCESS_LABEL" ?

Comment: Your code above includes several SQL statements. Which one is too slow?

Comment: I haven't tested statement by statement but ill do that now 
The thing is tho @Tim Williams that i use similar queries (i think even one of them is more complex than the ones i provided in this post) in another workbook and they reference another database inside the same server and it takes only 2-3 seconds like i said, so could it still be a query optimization issue?

Comment: Okay so i tested statement by statement and these are the results i got:
first query statement : 64 seconds
second query statement : 25 seconds
third query statement : 19 seconds
@jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it with the help of [@Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams).
I was missing indexes on some columns and after applying the indexes the waiting issue got resolved.
It went from having to wait a minute or more to get the information to basically being instantaneous. Thanks again Tim and  jarlh!